# How can you extract T-values from a multiple regression to put them in a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, linear-regression

When running a multiple regression, as shown here (data is from the 2014 and 2015 NHL seasons and is being used to predict wins):

```
TwoPredictorModel<-lm(Wins~Time.Shorthanded+Shots.per.Game, data=dat)
summary(TwoPredictorModel)
```

And yields the following outcome:

```
Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)      -18.042277  18.056039  -0.999 0.321903
Time.Shorthanded   0.009883   0.035455   0.279 0.781450
Shots.per.Game     1.889582   0.469588   4.024 0.000171
```

How can I extract the T-values in R to put them into a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull it out of the summary, eg

```
summary(lm(mpg~wt+hp, mtcars))$coefficients[,"t value"]
```